Show Splash Screen on Cache Miss to CanvasKit
I want to display a splash screen only if canvaskit.wasm is not available locally. I am fine using heuristics that are not always perfect.
The other option is to always show a splash screen, but I found it suboptimal because the splash screen gets discarded almost immediately and it gives a weird UI.

You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172517/14071053

Thanks for pointing me out to that resource. However I don’t see how it solves my current issue. I am already able to display a splash screen. I want to not show it when canvaskit.wasm is cached.
